# Emacs Live Syntax/Error Highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How do I make Emacs give me live feedback on my syntax?

Like, after I finish typing a line of code, how can I make it so that Emacs tells me if that line isn't using correct syntax?

For example, in Eclipse, it'll tell you before you compile when a line is not correct (in Java, at least). How can I mimic that behavior in Java, C, etc. for Emacs?

Thanks!

Running Emacs 24 in Terminal by the way. Installed via HomeBrew on OSX.

Comment: Typing a line of what? What syntax/language are you using? The question is not very clear. Please specify the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant for any language in general. For example, Eclipse does a syntax highlight for Java. (I'm doing C at the moment, but same concept).

Comment: http://www.flycheck.org/

Comment: It's not installing via MELPA. Keeps saying that the .el isn't found

Comment: Nevermind! It's installed. Not really what it looked like on the website, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs has a built-in mode called [FlyMake](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flymake.html) that can do this, provided you have a properly configured `makefile`.  Turn flymake on with `M-x flymake-mode`.  It runs an external command (by default `make check-syntax`) collects the errors and warnings and highlights the buffer appropriately.  It works pretty well for C and with some effort can be configured for other languages.

There is also an external package [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) that you can install with `M-x package-install flycheck`.  Turn it on with `M-x flycheck-mode`.  With most languages it Just Works with no further configuration.  You may need to install some external tool (for example `pylint` to check Python code).

Comment: It's working, but it's not working as it should, in my opinion. It highlights the words so much that I can't even read them properly, in full screen. Also highlights some function names and variable types for who knows why.

Comment: For `flycheck` you can customize the faces `flycheck-warning` and `flycheck-error` to change the highlighting.  There are similar faces for `flymake`.  A description of the error should appear in the minibuffer when you put the cursor over it.

Comment: I enabled flymake, intentionally misspelled a variable, intentionally misspelled a word in a comment. Nothing is highlighted. Any suggestions on how I can even begin to debug this?